# Text wrap on image using graphics?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, graphics2d

How I can wrap the text based on text size

```
g.drawString("Hello, please help me in wrapping the text", 100, 100);
```

output - Text in straight line:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUcMd.jpg]

Required output - Wrapped text based on text length:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MldhL.jpg]

How to achieve the required output? wasted lot of time in figuring it but no use, with explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: Your after [Drawing Multiple Lines of Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/drawmulstring.html)

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping words using HTML is the easiest way to approach to this problem.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LabelRenderTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String title = "<html><body style='"
                        + "text-align: center; width: 100px; padding: 5px;'>"
                        + "<p>Hello, please help me in<br>wrapping the text";

                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(
                        200,
                        100,
                        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

                JLabel textLabel = new JLabel(title);
                textLabel.setSize(textLabel.getPreferredSize());
                textLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

                Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
                textLabel.paint(g);
                g.dispose();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));
            }
        });
    }
}
```